# why do i keep getting a missing include file for d3dx11, x9..etc

Tags: directx-11

This is the most annoying thing ever I am TRYING to learn how to do directx, as impossible as that is already with Microsoft changing everything every 2 seconds, I actually found some tutorials I can use to help me learn. EVERY single tutorial I downloaded has had include file errors. "d3dx11.h no such file or directory" "d3dx10math.h no such file or directory" "d3dx9.h no such file or directory"

I have literally been picking apart the internet for the last 3 hours looking at every web page I can find that people had this same error, not one of them had a solution that actually worked.

I'm really looking for some help here, can someone who has had this issue before let me know how to solve this? I have the latest DirectX I'm pretty sure, I just got it so it has to be.

I do have Windows 8 and from what I have read that might be the issue, I saw a SO answer that may have as well been written in another language because it made no sense to me. I also tried to search for any of the files on my computer and did not find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the headers/libs path correctly?

```
i. Open Properties for the project and select the VC++ Directories page.
ii. Select All Configurations and All Platforms.
iii. Set these directories as follows:

    Executable Directories: <inherit from parent or project defaults> (On right-side drop-down)
    Include Directories: $(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
    Include Library Directories: $(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86

iv. Click Apply.
v. Choose the x64 Platform.
vi. Set the Library Directory as follows:

    Library Directories: $(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

see [where is the DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? Visual Studio? Anyways, you need to add the directories (the .h files) as part of your includes path, as well as the .lib files that match them. If you go to the following website, you select Tutorials, and you will have options for a version of DX and then you can follow the examples. But, regardsless the versions, the paths are pretty much the same, the difference will be the names of the files:

http://rastertek.com/